# How to pass value in url using web request GET method asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Am new to .Net and web service..i like to pass id through url..how to do that?whether it was done post or get method?guide me

```
string url = "http://XXXXX//"+id=22;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(xxxxx);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
//add properties
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
//convert 
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
//post data
Stream streamdata = request.GetRequestStream();
streamdata.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
streamdata.Close();
//response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Clean up the streams and the response.
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to build the URL with parameters (ref: Query String) then you can simply do:

`string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/?id={0}",22);`

[You can check this url, Passing variables between pages using QueryString at Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString)